# List layers in dataframe as parameters in script validation

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, arcgis-10.5, parameters, tool-validation

I'm trying to do some script validation in a tool I wrote. The user first selects a dataframe from the current mxd. This parameter works fine. When the user makes this selection, the next parameter, a list of layers in that dataframe should populate the next parameter. But all I get with the code below is an empty list. I can get layers for the entire mxd, but am unable to restrict it to the selected dataframe. This seems like something simple I'm missing. How can I accomplish this?

```
def initializeParameters(self):
"""Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
called when the tool is opened.
Populates data frame parameter with data frames in map and disables other
parameters.
"""
try:   # this works
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
    dflist = [df.name for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)]
    self.params[0].filter.type = "ValueList"
    self.params[0].filter.list = dflist
    del mxd
except:
    arcpy.AddError("\nMust run this tool in ArcMap, not ArcCatalog")

self.params[1].enabled = False
self.params[2].enabled = False

return



def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')

    if self.params[0].value:
        self.params[1].enabled = True

        # this does not work the way I want
        layerList = [lyr.name for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, self.params[0].value) if not lyr.isGroupLayer]

        uniqueList = list(set(layerList))
        uniqueList.sort()

        self.params[1].filter.type = "ValueList"
        self.params[1].filter.list = uniqueList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is wrong:

```
layerList = [lyr.name for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, self.params[0].value) if not lyr.isGroupLayer]
```

A `ListLayers()` requires an `mxd` *or* a `dataframe`, not both.  So should be

```
layerList = [lyr.name for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.params[0].value) if not lyr.isGroupLayer]
```

Here is the entire `updateParameters(self)` function that worked for me.  I had to get the Data Frame using `arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames()` and then use that in the `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()`.

```
def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')

    if self.params[0].value:
        self.params[1].enabled = True

        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, self.params[0].value)[0]

        if df:
            layerList = [lyr.name for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df) if not lyr.isGroupLayer]
            uniqueList = list(set(layerList))
            uniqueList.sort()
            self.params[1].filter.list = uniqueList
```

Selecting the first Dataframe gives a list of the layers in that frame:
[image]

Selecting the second Dataframe then shows the list of those layers:
[image]

Note that if you select your dataframe, and then a layer, but then decide to change the dataframe you may see an error.  This is just telling you that the currently selected layer is not in the list of layers.  Selecting a valid layer will remove the error.  There is probably a way to get around that error, but I didn't find it in my brief look.